# What is the word for toilet stick (if there is one)?

Tags: single-word-requests

Before toilet paper (or any paper in general) comes around, some people would use sticks or similar things instead. Is there a general term (slang is fine but prefer dictionary) to describe those sticks? If so what it is?

P.S.
I had read it over internet a couple of years ago but I can't find it anymore. It could had been an invalid word.

Comment: I'm tempted to assume that it is like how the British refer to everything that deals with done deals in the loo: some construction that begins with bog-*.

Comment: Pretty sure this question is a dupe.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm not kidding. I really am finding the word.

Comment: @PhillipSiebold Can you think of a specific one for this case?

Comment: @Penguinlay for example, **bogwater** refers to soiled water in the toilet.  **bogroll** refers to the roll of toilet paper.

Comment: @PhillipSiebold Oh, I meant can you think of a specific term to describe this using bog prefix?

Answer (score 1):

"**Shit stick** means "a thin stake or stick used instead of toilet paper" and was a historical item of material culture introduced through Chinese Buddhism and Japanese Buddhism. A well-known example is gānshǐjué/kanshiketsu (lit. 乾屎橛 "dry shit stick") from the Chan/Zen gōng'àn/kōan in which a monk asked "What is Buddha?" and Master Yunmen/Unmon answered "A dry shit stick".

"The English language has some shit(e) stick lexical parallels to these Asian language terms. The Oxford English Dictionary (s.v. shit, shite n.) quotes two early shit-stick examples: "a hard chuffe, a shite-sticks" (1598) and "a shite-sticks, a shite-rags, that is to say, a miserable pinch-pennie" (1659); and (s.v. poop n.2) defines poop-stick as "a fool, ineffectual person", with the earliest usage in 1930."

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shit_stick

Comment: Nice research! The closest I could found was xylospongium. I will wait for a single word term (without the sponge) other people might find.